# Why ist "Edit Variables" is disabled for IntelliJ live tempates?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to define a live template in IntelliJ. Unfortunatley I cannot use any variables and the "Edit Variables" buttons remains disabled for new templates. Any ideas how to get variable substitution working?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variable is needed in the "Template Text" in order for the button to become enabled. The variables should start and end with the "$" as depicted in below picture:
[image]